# What is a better way to query a ManyToManyField for speed? entire object or id only?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to query a `ManyToManyField` for speed.

I have 2 options that I know of:

1. Add the entire object to the field
2. Add just the id to the field

If I add the object, obviously with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, I get that benefit, which is huge, but I'm afraid adding it might slow query speed down because it's getting an entire object, and many of them at that.

Whereas with just the id, it's just an int, so less heavy, and faster I assume.

For speed only, what would you suggest?

Comment: Can you give an example of the Django ORM query you're going to perform?

Comment: are you using `djangorestframework`? do you want to retrieve data fast from the backend server? pls show code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provide [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to make your query faster for `ManyToMany` field or reverse `ForeignKey` field.
and [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for normal `ForeignKey` field.

Comment: That'll do. Thanks. Even better than my id work around.